How to change individual views within another view?
I am working on a way to create a letterBox that is composed of a rounded rectangle, invisible text field, and Text view that displays the last letter in the text field. This letterBox is then put in a row based on the length of the wanted word.
My intention is for on click of each of the individual boxes, the box changes color and then that text field and Text View is changed. Currently, the letterBox that is experiencing the text change is not the selected value and is unpredictable.
These are the two classes that I am working with.
import SwiftUI

struct LetterBox: View {
    @State var letter: String
    var status: LetterStatus
    var boxColor: Color {
        switch status {
        case .changing:
            return Color(.metallicSeaweed)
        case .notChanging:
            return Color(.platinum)
        case .acceptable:
            return Color(.yellowGreenCrayola)
        case .notAcceptable:
            return Color(.rubyRed)
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4)
                .style(withStroke: Color.black, lineWidth: 1, fill: boxColor)
                .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
            TextField("", text: $letter)
                .font(.custom("Lovely Madness", size: 55))
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .tint(Color.clear)
                .foregroundColor(Color.clear)
            if letter.isEmpty {
                Text(" ")
                    .font(.custom("Lovely Madness", size: 55))
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            } else {
                Text(String(letter.last!))
                    .font(.custom("Lovely Madness", size: 55))
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            }
        }
    }
    
}

enum LetterStatus {
    case changing
    case notChanging
    case acceptable
    case notAcceptable
}

extension Shape {
    func style<StrokeStyle: ShapeStyle, FillStyle: ShapeStyle>(
        withStroke strokeContent: StrokeStyle,
        lineWidth: CGFloat = 1,
        fill fillContent: FillStyle
    ) -> some View {
        stroke(strokeContent, lineWidth: lineWidth)
            .background(fill(fillContent))
    }
}

struct LetterBox_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LetterBox(letter: .init("J"), status: .notChanging)
            .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 100, height: 100))
        LetterBox(letter: .init("A"), status: .changing)
            .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 100, height: 100))
    }
}

import SwiftUI

struct LetterBoxRowFunctional: View {
    
    var word: String
    var row: [GridItem] {
        [GridItem(.fixed(CGFloat(word.count)))]
    }
    var boxSize: CGFloat {
        switch word.count {
        case 6:
            return 60
        default:
            return 75
        }
    }
    @State var letterBoxArray: [LetterBox]
    @State var selected: Int = -1
    @State var userEntry: String = ""
    @FocusState var keyboardFocused: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            LazyHGrid(rows: row) {
                ForEach (0...word.count - 1, id: \.self) { num in
                    letterBoxArray[num]
                        .frame(width: boxSize, height: boxSize)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            changeStatusToChanging(index: num, len: word.count, array: &letterBoxArray)
                            selected = num
                            print(selected)
                        }
                }
            }
            TextField("", text: $userEntry)
                .keyboardType(.alphabet)
                .foregroundStyle(Color.clear)
                .tint(Color.clear)
                .focused($keyboardFocused)
                .autocorrectionDisabled(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/true/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                .onChange(of: userEntry.count | selected ) {
                    if selected >= 0 {
                        letterBoxArray[selected].letter = String(userEntry.suffix(1))
                    }
                }
        }.onAppear(perform: {keyboardFocused = true})
    }
    
    init(word: String) {
        self.word = word
        self.letterBoxArray = getLetterBoxArray(word: word)
    }
}

func getLetterBoxArray(word: String) -> [LetterBox] {
    var arr: [LetterBox] = []
    for char in word {
        arr += [LetterBox(letter: String(char), status: .notChanging)]
    }
    return arr
}

func changeStatusToChanging(index: Int, len: Int, array: inout [LetterBox]) {
    for idx in 0...len - 1 {
        if idx == index {
            array[idx].status = .changing
        } else {
            array[idx].status = .notChanging
        }
    }
}

struct LetterBoxRowFunctionalPreview: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LetterBoxRowFunctional(word: "love")
    }
}

I am also getting this Error Message: Error: this application, or a library it uses, has passed an invalid numeric value (NaN, or not-a-number) to CoreGraphics API and this value is being ignored. Please fix this problem.

State should aways be private
